# Does this curiousity have any meaning?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, pi

If $\pi$ is calculated to the $360$-th digit after the decimal point, the last
digits are $360$ :

```
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089
98628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450
28410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316
52712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881
74881520920962829254091715364367892590360
```

A full angle has $360$°.

- Is this pure chance, or does this curiousity have any meaning ?

Comment: And a full angle has $400$ grad, and also $2\pi$ etc...

Comment: That's indeed funny, though I don't think it has any deep meaning. For one, it is entirely dependent on writing $\pi$ in *decimal* positional notation and angles in *degrees*, which are entirely arbitrary choices. On the other hand, you might like to know that it is conjectured that every possible (contiguous) sequence of finitely many digits appears infinitely often in the $b$-ary expansion of $\pi$, for any integer $b \geq 2$ (i.e. $\pi$ is thought to be a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)).

Comment: There is nothing mathematically significant about $360^\circ$ degrees of a circle, other than that it's a round number.

Comment: If you calculate it to $1$ digit after the decimal point, the last digit is $1$, the unit! I would say that is more (although not very) interesting.

Comment: @A.P. I know this conjecture, but intuitively, I would tend to believe that $\pi$ is not normal.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what kind of intuition would lead to that conclusion.

Comment: @Peter Why not? After all, almost every real number is normal (in the sense that the set of non-normal real numbers has Lebesgue measure $0$).

Comment: @Peter This is similarly coincidental, but you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_point

Comment: I think any finite number sequence you can think of will turn up somewhere in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ (with some kind of "probability 1" caveat).

Comment: @Paul Unfortunately, only very short sequences can be checked to be or not to be in $\pi$. But the question of normality is even more philosphocial than my question, and has virtually nothing to do with it.

Comment: I would understand why the normality of $\pi$ and many more other mathematical constants is conjectured, if it would at least have been shown that each digit appears infinite many often. But this was not shown for any not-constructed number, as far as I know.

Comment: It is even unknown, whether, lets say, $7$ appears finite many or infinite many often in $\pi$. So, the only reason to the conjecture is the calculation of many digits. I read a nice article about the "Law of low numbers". There are some conjectures with very very large counterexamples. So, there is no reason, why the things are different in the case of the normality of some number.

Comment: There is a difference to, for example, Goldbachs conjecture. It has not been proven, but there are very good reasons to believe it to be true. But enough about normality ...

Comment: @Travis you beat me to the punch

Comment: @ip6 Of course, there are only so many famous numerical happenstances in the decimal expansion of $\pi$. :)

Comment: @Peter You might also be interested in http://oeis.org/A057680 and http://oeis.org/A064810, which both record sequences of "self-locating" strings in $\pi$. These both use different indexing conventions, and both of these are different from the one in your question.

Comment: It has no meaning (unless it's one of God's little jokes), but I like it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(The following is not meant to be serious mathematics.)

In decimal there are $1000$ three place numbers. The probability that at the $N^{\rm th}$ decimal place of $\pi$ the last three figures enounce exactly the number $N$ therefore is ${1\over1000}$, and the probability that this does not happen is ${999\over1000}$. Assuming independence of the involved events, the probability of failure at all decimals up to the $700^{\rm th}$, say, therefore comes to about $$\left({999\over1000}\right)^{700}<{1\over2}\ .$$
This means that we can expect such an event to happen in the first $700$ decimal places of $\pi$ with a probability $>{1\over2}$.

Comment: "The probability that at the $N^{\rm th}$ decimal place of $\pi$ the last three figures enounce exactly the number $N$ therefore is ${1\over1000}$ [...]" : aren't you assuming that $\pi$ is normal in base $10$ when you say this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not meant to be serious mathematics"? This is actually a pretty sensible estimate. The only problem I see is that you are using an assumption on the distribution of finite sequences in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ which, as far as I know, hasn't been proved. It does follow from normality, though, and proving consequences of some conjecture is perfectly fine, as long as you explicitly point out what is still unproved.